# Three-way comparison operator<=> (starship operator) in C++ on floating-point types

Tags: c++, nan, c++20, spaceship-operator

How does the starship operator (operator `<=>`) in C++ handle NANs when being used on values of type `double` and `float`? Is it UB, unspecified behaviour, or does it do something sensible, e.g., compare two NANs as equal etc...?

Comment: _"something sensible, e.g., compare two NANs as equal"_ - Never.

Comment: One of the essential properties of NaN is that it's not comparable.  Any comparison, even to itself, returns false.

Comment: You can make your own comparator for floats, possibly using `std::fpclassify` to categorize as primary comparison criterion, and then by value for where that makes sense.